# AVD for Samsung Galaxy S4(1080X1920) showing Black screen

Tags: android, android-emulator

After searching a lot, I found out this link : http://developer.sonymobile.com/knowledge-base/sdks/sony-add-on-sdk/install-the-sony-add-on-sdk/

Following the steps as per the instruction, I have created AVD for 1080x1920 screen resolution,i.e., Xperia Z. But still when I try to run this emulator, it display nothing but a blank screen, seems not working at all. Also checked the "Use Host GPU" option. But no result???? Can anyone please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I cannot answer your question precisely but here I am trying to figure out some problems. 
First of all high resolution needs HD screen. Are your computer/laptop screen is HD??? If not, you cannot open HD avd. 
Another thing is, high resolution needs extra memory size allocation.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem, then I found this solution.

I checked "Use host GPU emulation" option for avd. Also keep in mind that your system must have graphics card (GPU) installed in it.

Answer (score 0):

use the following steps to make avd for s4 or any type:withe help of genymotion third party pulgin:

download first genymotion
https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/launchpad/download/

cmd for install genymotion
http://schier.co/post/install-genymotion-2.0-in-ubuntu

then:
The installation of the plugin can be done by launching Eclipse and going to "Help / Install New Software" menu, then just add a new Update Site with the following URL: http://plugins.genymotion.com/eclipse.

installing the google play service from the following :
http://blog.zeezonline.com/2013/11/install-google-play-on-genymotion-2-0/

Enjoy its working.